# Why banned from asking question?

Tags: support

I don't understand why I should be banned from asking question on English Language & Usage. May you remove the block, please.

Answer (score 7):

**It's not possible for staff or moderators to manually remove an automatic block.** There's a lot of information about question banning on [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th). Users who post a lot of poor questions will usually get a notification warning them about post quality. It appears you haven't had one of those — that's unusual and a little unfortunate.

The only way of reversing a question ban is to improve your existing questions to get them upvoted. When the system next examines them, it may decide to remove the ban, or perhaps to allow a limited number of questions per week. You might get one question every six months.

You can find a list of questions [in your profile](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/140628/sapiens?tab=questions) and at the bottom of that list a link to deleted questions. Of your ten questions, half are either downvoted, closed or deleted
— or even downvoted, closed *and* deleted.

When you edit your questions to improve them (and vote to undelete them if necessary), they will be bumped on the front page and will gain more attention. This can be good! But the extra attention could also mean you get more downvotes if you don't improve them enough or rectify their on-topic-ness. You may want to re-compose the questions offline and then edit them when you're completely happy.

Comment: "The only way of reversing a question ban is to improve your existing questions to get them upvoted."

So, how reasonable is that?

As we all know, many sites are filled with argumentative trolls, who obtain their satisfaction by destroying for others. It is unfortunate that SE does not have mechanisms to avoid such nonsense.

I am very sorry, but I will not do a bit more to avoid the ban.

Comment: Stack Exchange has several mechanisms to prevent users with unconstructive motivations from causing harm to the communities hosted. Blocking those who continually post poor quality questions is one of them. Blaming a Q-ban on "argumentative trolls" (which can be flagged for moderator attention and removed, and has nothing to do with the contents of one's own posts) is ignoring the cause, and will not result in a change of effect. @Sapiens

Comment: @Nij I did not blame argumentative trolls. Rather, I expressed interest in such mechanisms as you are providing one example of.

Comment: @Sapiens If, as Andrew Leach suggests, you haven't received notifications, you might have been affected by the banning of someone else on your IP address. The [Meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) Andrew Leach linked to says, "If you really, really think the ban is an error, then email the team directly using the "contact us" link provided at the bottom of every page." Give it a try. Let them know you haven't received any warnings (if that was the case) before being banned.